# Error when extracting text

Tags: itext

Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfLiteral' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfNumber'.

CODE:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

SimpleTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

for (int p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
{

    text.AppendLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, p, strategy));
}
reader.Close();
return text.ToString();
```

Only get this error with a very few pdfs. Any ideas?

STACK TRACE:

```
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ShowTextArray.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
   at DCS.Common.PDF.Functions.GetTextPdf(PdfReader reader) in C:\Users\rmaldonado\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DCS\Contract\Common\PDF\Functions.cs:line 35
   at DCS.Common.PDF.Functions.ParsePDF(Byte[] bytes) in C:\Users\rmaldonado\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DCS\Contract\Common\PDF\Functions.cs:line 23
   at DCS.CAPPS.BLL.Common.Attachment.ReParseText() in C:\Users\rmaldonado\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DCS\Contract\ContractBLL\Common\Common.cs:line 1120
```

Comment: Please provide samples of those pdfs or at least the stack trace of those exceptions. It might be am error in iText or in the pdfs.

Comment: I added stack trace in the OP

Comment: [PDF](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4cQ-iOkdWKvM1RtaEJ3YjFrYkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I analyzed your PDF, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15572486/1729265) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page content of your document [Mod 2.pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4cQ-iOkdWKvM1RtaEJ3YjFrYkU/edit?usp=sharing) is utterly broken. It actually is broken so badly Adobe Preflight (from Acrobat 9.5.4) just like iText runs into an error while trying to analyze it.

A manual inspection indicates that the most obvious errors relate to operations injected into an array of operands of **TJ** operations, e.g.

```
[(OMB) 0.0 Tc -278.0 (Approval) 0.0 Tc -278.0 (2700-0042) ] TJ

[(AMENDMENT) 0.0 Tc -278.0 (OF) 0.0 Tc -278.0 (SOLICITATION/MODIFICATION)
 0.0 Tc -278.0 (OF) 0.0 Tc -278.0 (CONTRACT) ] TJ
```

This pattern continues, i.e. every non-trivial **[ ... ] TJ** operation contains injected **0.0 Tc** operations.

This is wrong, cf. section 7.8.2 of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> In PDF, all of the operands needed by an operator shall immediately precede that operator. Operators do not return results, and operands shall not be left over when an operator finishes execution.

This makes `PdfContentStreamProcessor.ShowTextArray.Invoke` (responsible for processing **TJ** operations) run into the error. As the operand array of **TJ** may contain only strings and numbers, everything which is not a `PdfString,` is cast to `PdfNumber` but the **Tc** operators are instances of `PdfLiteral.`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but today I ran into same problem. I'm using iTextSharp version 5.5.7 and  same error occurred. I'm trying to extract text from very old PDF files, so they might be corrupted. For now my solution is to put text extraction into `try catch` block and hold list of files that need to be manually opened. Question is two years old so maybe something changed and there is something I can do in code to get this working. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: In case of the OP's PDF the contents simply were utterly broken, there is not much one can do beyond catching the exception and ignoring the file. Whether or not your files are similarly badly broken, I cannot tell without inspecting them. If they are, the code written for valid PDF files won't help you, you'd need to write a custom parser component.

Answer (score 1):

for extracting text from pdf ,try using this code given below

```
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, p, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy())
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mkl said there might be an error in PDf too. try to copy paste the text contents from PDf to notepad. Is it coming blank .Just to check whether the contents are in image format or any other format. And Provide the complete code if possible.